# how could i store docs pdf image files in database using stored procedure in C#

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

i have written code following code to store the pdf/docs/image files in database, using c#.net
and sql server 2008 stored procedure but i am unable to do that after converted file in byte array.

Code:

```
 private void bttnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            FrmAccept sForm = new FrmAccept();
            sForm.ShowDialog();
            if (FrmAccept.strMsg == "YES")
            {
                sFunctionQuotationSave();
                MessageBox.Show("Data Saved Successfully", "Insert Record", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);

            }
            else
            { return; }
        }

        public void sFunctionQuotationSave()
        {
            SERIALNUMBER = 1;
            Int32 Id = Convert.ToInt32(sSearch);

            String bytestring = null;
            for (int i = 0; i < dgvQuotationVouchers.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                string filename = dgvQuotationVouchers.Rows[i].Cells[5].Value.ToString();
                MessageBox.Show("FIlePAth>>" + filename);


                byte[] bytes = File.ReadAllBytes(dgvQuotationVouchers.Rows[i].Cells[5].Value.ToString());
                SqlParameter fileP = new SqlParameter("Upload", SqlDbType.VarBinary);
                fileP.Value = bytes;
                SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand();


                SqlCommand sqlcomm = new SqlCommand();
                sqlcomm.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Upload", SqlDbType.VarBinary)).Value = bytes;

                dt = sFunctions.ExecuteQuery(Variables.con, "Quotation_Master", "usp_Quotation_Master " + Id + ",'" + dgvQuotationVouchers.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value + "'," + Variables.sTendercode + "," + txtIndentNo.Text + ",'" + dgvQuotationVouchers.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value + "','" + dgvQuotationVouchers.Rows[i].Cells[4].Value + "','" + dgvQuotationVouchers.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value + "','" + dgvQuotationVouchers.Rows[i].Cells[5].Value + "'," + + ",'" + Variables.LocationId + "'," + false + ",'" + Variables.Layer + "'," + rbtnLocal.Checked + "," + rbtnGlobal.Checked + "," + false + "");
                }
            }
             MessageBox.Show("BYTE_DATA>>\n"+bytestring);
       }
```

Comment: Please, clarify your question. What is what you're unable to do?

Comment: i am unable to store byte array value in above  code to the database field which is upload and its datatype is varbinary max

Comment: You're unable, but why? What's is the error you're receiving?

Comment: i dont know how to pass byte array value in to the database field

Comment: actually i dont know how to pass value of byte array in parameter of executequery();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have 2 SqlCommand objects in your code.. And none has the command text property set..

You should have something like this instead:

```
SqlParameter fileP = new SqlParameter("@Upload", SqlDbType.VarBinary);
fileP.Value = bytes; //Here, you're assigning the value to the parameter.
SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand();
myCommand.Connection = someSqlConnection;
myCommand.CommandText = "YOUR UPDATE STATEMENT";
myCommand.Parameters.Add(fileP);
myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: Okay thanks,
but what if i want to pass value in executequery() is their any solution ?

Comment: hello , when i store with the file without using stored procedures then it is easily get done...
but i want to do that using store procedure that i dont get it how to do that.

Comment: @ShivomBhatt I don't understand what you mean with "pass value in executequery()". This method has no parameters. About direct text vs stored procedure, the changes are commandtype and commandtext properties, the rest is exactly the same.

Comment: Okay, i mean to say that i am passing all the values through executequery() which you can see in my given code snippet.

so i want to know is there any way to store file using execute()

Comment: @ShivomBhatt Still don't understand what you mean with "store file using execute()". Execute is a method related to a database command, so I don't see how it relates to writing a file in any sense.. Do you know about the single responsibility principle? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle

Comment: No i don't know about it, i am trying your suggestion and let you know if any query i have thank you for your support.